# Como solucionar problema al mostrar URL que tiene certificado de seguridad

Tags: android, url, webview

Cuando muestro una url que tiene certificado de seguridad (https://), la vista se queda en blanco, pero los que no tienen certificado de seguridad cargan sin problema (http://).

A continuación el código que muestra la vista de la página con certificado de seguridad, uso un contenedor webView.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_noticias, container, false);

    WebView view=(WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.wv_noticias);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());// Agregamos un WebViewCliente, esto permite que se sigan ejecutando los links dentro de este WebView
    //view.loadUrl(url);
    /****************************************/
    if (isOnline(getActivity())) {
    String url="https://www.uniagustiniana.edu.co/Noticias/";

        view.loadUrl(url);
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"SI hay conexión!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/pagina_error.html");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"NO hay 
    conexión!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    /****************************************/

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Agregué una respuesta Ivan. Puedes identificar el tipo de error pero en este caso solo debes proceder a cargar la página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando el [WebClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) debes sobre escribir el método [**onReceivedSslError()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedSslError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.SslErrorHandler,%20android.net.http.SslError)).

> [**onReceivedSslError()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedSslError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.SslErrorHandler,%20android.net.http.SslError)) Notifica a la aplicación host que se
> produjo un error SSL al cargar un recurso. La aplicación host debe
> llamar a `handler.cancel()` o `handler.proceed()`.

Ejemplo:

```
WebView view=(WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.wv_noticias);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            
            ...
            ...
            ...

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                String message = "SSL Certificate error.";
                switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
                    case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                        message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                        break;
                    case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                        message = "The certificate has expired.";
                        break;
                    case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                        message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                        break;
                    case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                        message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                        break;
                }
                message += "\"SSL Certificate Error\" Do you want to continue anyway?.. YES";

                handler.proceed();

                Log.e(TAG, onReceivedSslError: " + message);
            }

        });
```

Lo común es cancelar la carga pero en este caso simplemente indica que continué mediante `handler.proceed()`

---

#### Actualización:

En el caso de subir una aplicación a Google Play Store se debe tener cuidado ya que seguramente no será aceptada, la razón es que si ocurre un error SSL la página no debe cargarse al contrario se debe proceder a cancelarla, esto por cuestiones de seguridad.

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387?hl=en

Para esto debes implementar un diálogo el cual indique al usuario si desea proceder o cancelar la carga, con esto tu aplicación podrá ser subida a Google Play Store sin problema.

```
  @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomWebView.this);
        String message = "";
        switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
            case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                break;
            case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                message = "The certificate has expired.";
                break;
            case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                break;
            case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        message += "\"SSL Certificate Error\" Deseas continuar?";

        builder.setTitle("SSL Certificate Error");
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("continuar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                handler.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
      }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias lo estoy ajustando, porque la respuesta de arriba me había funcionado en el emulador pero me lo rechazó la playstores (Políticas del Programa para Desarrolladores de Google), ahora estoy ajustando con tu respuesta muchas gracias.

Comment: @IvanAlfredo con respecto a lo que comentas, es importante saber que si ocurre un error ssl , se supone que no se debe proceder a cargar la página, Actualice mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jorgesys ya verifiqué en el emulador y acabo de subir la actualización ahora debo esperar que aparezca la actualización para verlo en el celular.

Comment: Subí un nuevo APK con con las correcciones pero no me lo acepta aún, me indica el mismo error de politicas (SSL Error Handler) pero no se si es que toca eliminar el anterior APK, lo que hice fue aumentar el versión code porque no veo como eliminar el anterior.

Comment: No se puede eliminar @IvanAlfredo tienes que subir un nuevo. Apk con un versionCode mayor.

Comment: ya esta actualizada la app, lo que me pone una duda es que si ahora estoy mostrando una página que tiene certificado de seguridad, ¿porque el mensaje dice que el certificado de seguridad no es de confianza? me puedes orientar porfa.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día Ivan solo tienes que agregar un WebViewClient puedes agregarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
        }
    });
```

espero te sea de utilidad saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias me ha funcionado con esta solución.

Comment: En el emulador me había funcionado pero me lo rechaza en la carga a playstore por Políticas del Programa para Desarrolladores de Google, ahora estoy trabajando nuevamente en ello.